# How to set different path of an API that is present in the same WSDL in Ready API or

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I have a WSDL which has two APIs and both of them have different path.

How to parameterize the environment variables in Ready API where path is different for one API Name. It disables the URL as soon some environment is selected.

For example:

${baseURL}/path1 Is it possible to keep path1 enabled and only baseURL is parmeterized for different environments ST, SIT, UAT etc?

[image]

Comment: Hi, are you using SoapUI (open source) or the licensed ReadyAPI?  Also, the API section is where you define the API of interest, beyond checking the request works, you dont call the API form here.  Instead, you create functional tests.  Then you can mess with parameterisation and environments.

Comment: I am using Ready API. I have created functional tests and there the parameterization is done. Ready API has a functional where when you define new environment and select that it will automatically disable the endpoint in the test case.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Not yet. In ReadyAPI I can’t use environments feature due to above and had to switch back to using default environment and then the endpoint doesn’t disable and have to manually change the environment variable name from project properties everytime to make it work. Not a good solution though but selecting environment should not disabled endpoint for request. As when there are multiple APIs with different path in same WSDLs Ready API environment feature can’t be used